# Using Retrofit 2 in Intent Service class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, intentservice

I am trying to fetch data from server and sync it on the background of app. I did it using AsyncTask in an Intent Service class, but now I want to make network call using Retrofit. So, I fetched data from server using retrofit but while I am saving them on the local database the main thread freezes, only after completion of the process I can do something on the Main thread. Why is this happening?

I tried both synchronus and Asynchronus request of retrofit but the problem remains. This is what I have tried so far..

```
//calling company api in synchronus way

    try {
        val responseCompany = apiService.company(page, headers, bodyModel).execute()
        Log.e("onResponse", "Company Response Code: ${responseCompany.code()}")
        Log.e("onResponse", "Company Response Body: ${Gson().toJson(responseCompany.body())}")

        if (responseCompany.isSuccessful) {
            val response = responseCompany.body()

            //delete company data
            if (response?.delete?.data?.size!! > 0) {
                for (i in response.delete.data.indices) {

                    val delete = response.delete.data[i]
                    Log.e(tag, "Delete Company data $i: ${delete.company_id}")
                    dbAdapter.open()
                    dbAdapter.Delete_COMPANY_NAME(delete.company_id)
                    dbAdapter.close()
                }
            }

            //insert company data
            if (response.insert.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (i in response.insert.data.indices) {
                    val insert = response.insert.data[i]
                    Log.e(tag, "Insert company data $i: ${insert.company_id}")
                    dbAdapter.open()
                    dbAdapter.Insert_COMPANY_NAME(insert.company_id.toString(), insert.company_name)
                    dbAdapter.close()
                }
            }

            //update company data
            if (response.update.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (i in response.update.data.indices) {
                    val update = response.update.data[i]
                    Log.e(tag, "Update Company data $i: ${update.company_id}")
                    dbAdapter.open()
                    dbAdapter.Update_COMPANY_NAME(update.company_id.toString(), update.company_name)
                    dbAdapter.close()
                }
            }

            val totalPage = largest(response.delete.meta.pagination.total_pages, response.insert.meta.pagination.total_pages, response.update.meta.pagination.total_pages)


                    if (page < totalPage) {
                        prefManager.pageNumber = page + 1
                        bodyModel.date = lastAdUpdate2
                        bodyModel.limit = 500
                        companyData(bodyModel)
                    } else {
                        prefManager.T_COMPANY_NAME = currentTime
                        prefManager.PAGE_NUMBER = 1
                        prefManager.TOTAL_PAGE = 1
                        prefManager.pageNumber = 1
                        prefManager.FIRST = "1"
                        pagenumber = prefManager.PAGE_NUMBER

                        Handler().postDelayed({
                            bodyModel.limit = 100
                            bodyModel.date = lastAdUpdate3
                            generics(bodyModel)
                        }, 1000)
                    }
        } else {
            prefManager.dbUpdateStatus = false
            Log.i("dataNotInsert", "data Not Insert")
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Company: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

N.B: I made network call (Retrofit request) in an Intent Service class..

Any Kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Whats your error?

Comment: no error, its just freezes/hangs the main thread, whereas while using AsyncTask the main thread was not freezing.

Comment: So are you want to data in the background?

Comment: Yes , I want the whole process to occur in background without interfering the main thread.

Comment: Then use Kotlin Coroutines for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, I did solve it using Coroutine, forgot to update. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was actually solved by replacing **Intent Service** with **Work Manager**. And Using **Kotlin Coroutine**

And if you want to persist with **Intent Service** rather than using **WorkManager**. Just wrapping your network call with **AsyncTask** will solve the problem